# Dot Net 4.5 doesn't have DataTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2013, datatable

I'm using .NET 4.5 , and when I do this :

```
 DataTable table_DropDownSelections = new DataTable();
```

On Visual Studio 2013 , I get a red line that says :

> the type of reference name datatable could not be found

And when I do this :

```
        using System.Data;
```

I get the same error  .

Dot Net 4.5 doesn't have a Data Table ? From the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I see that it does .

Thanks

Comment: Does your project have a reference to the `System.Data` assembly?

Comment: @Dirk: I tried it , doesn't work .

Comment: @DStanley: I did , doesn't work .

Comment: You've answered your question - yes it exists.  Either you haven't referenced the assembly or you don't have the right `using` directive (they're two different things).

Comment: What if you changed to `System.Data.DataTable table_DropDownSelections = new System.Data.DataTable();`?  That would tell you if you have the assembly referenced.

Comment: @DStanley: I tried that also , doesn't work . Am I missing something ? I'm sure the project is in 4.5 .

Comment: Do you get the same error?  If not post it.  Do you have more that one project in your solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DataTable` is a class, you can't include them in `using` statement. You need to include the namespace only like:

```
using System.Data;
```

You can also right click on the `DataTable` in your code and select resolve. This will let you include the required namepsace like:

[image]

Make sure you have a reference added to `System.Data` assembly in your project references.

[image]

If you don't find the reference then right click on project references and select add references, go to "Assemblies". There select `System.Data` and click add.

Comment: I don't have a "resolve" , when doing a right click , only Generate .

Comment: @ron, make sure you have added reference to `System.Data` in your project references.

Comment: @ron 

It should be a default Reference

C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.dll

Comment: OK , I searched there but the dll is not there . What should I do ? This is clearly the problem , thanks for enlightening me

Comment: @ron, right click on the project, click add references, go to "Assemblies", There search for `System.Data`

Answer (score 1):

Try to add System.Data.dll manually into your porject

Comment: I don't have it in the "Add reference" , the DLL is not there .

Comment: Even if you clicked RMB on References -> add Reference.. -> Assembles and type System.Data to search for??